# .load() not working on page with same domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to load a div from one page to another on the same site. I don't get any errors, but the div doesn't populate

```
$("#review-1").load("https://www.someurl.com div[data-comment-id='111']");
$("#review-2").load("https://www.someurl.com div[data-comment-id='222']");
```

ajax get doesnt work either

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.someurl.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
        $(data.responseText).find('div[data-comment-id="111"]').each(function(){
            $('#review-1').append($(this).html());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(data.responseText)` is incorrect...no such property.

Comment: @charlietfl i saw that on another stackoverflow question, and it worked for them. but if i take that out here, nothing happens. it pulls in the entire html instead of the div but still doesnt populate where i want it to

Comment: for starters ...check if ajax success is even being fired. put a console log or alert in there

Comment: so the status is 200, and there is no error. console.log('blah') shows nothing and obviously, im still having issues with it not populating my div. like i said before though it pulls in the html from the other page, but all of it, not just the div i want. is this because i am selecting it by an attribute? it is the only unique identifier, and i dont have access to add an id or class to the element that i need to pull from